# How to use pyinstaller in subprocess windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess, pyinstaller

It worked for me in the cmd.exe console:

```
C:\tools\python2-x86_32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --name="Name app" --onefile --windowed --icon=tk.ico script.py
```

But I need to compile python

This does not work:

```
subprocess.call(['C:\tools\python2-x86_32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe ','--name','Name app','--onefile ','--windowed','--icon=','tk.ico','script.py'])
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/usercom/Documents/sql_alpha/sqlms.py", line 96, in <module>
>     subprocess.call(['C:\tools\python2-x86_32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe
> ```
>
> ','--name','Analysis log Pre-Alpha 1','--onefile
>   ','--windowed','--icon=','tk.ico','tk.py'])
>         File "C:\tools\python2-x86_32\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
>           return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
>         File "C:\tools\python2-x86_32\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
>           errread, errwrite)
>         File "C:\tools\python2-x86_32\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
>           startupinfo)
>       WindowsError: [Error 2]

This does not work:

```
cmd = 'C:\tools\python2-x86_32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --name="Name app" --onefile --windowed --icon=tk.ico script.py'
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

> ```
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/usercom/Documents/sql_alpha/sqlms.py", line 97, in <module>
>     subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>   File "C:\tools\python2-x86_32\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
>     errread, errwrite)
>   File "C:\tools\python2-x86_32\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
>     startupinfo)
> ```

```
WindowsError: [Error 5]
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Can you try replacing `'Name app'` with `'"Name app"'`

Comment: Error 5 corresponds to access denied. So can you try running your python script as administrator.

Comment: It does not change anything ( 'Name app' with '"Name app"' .

Comment: I run my script in  cmd.exe as administrator .
It does not change anything

Comment: Use a raw string: `cmd = r'C:\tools\python2-x86_32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --name="Name app" --onefile --windowed --icon=tk.ico script.py'`. The string literal `'\t'` is a tab character if you don't use a raw string.

Comment: eryksun@ thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
subprocess.call([r'C:\tools\python2-x86_32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe','--name','Name app', '--onefile','--windowed','tk.py'])
```

Thanks Tarun Behal!
Thanks eryksun!